# Options for additional loan to add a second story to house

Tags: mortgage, refinance, home-equity

I would like to add a second story to my primary residence in the US. Estimated cost of project is $250k. I'm seven years in on a 30 year fixed rate mortgage at 3.75%. What are typical options people go with to get a loan of that size? (if at all possible).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refinance into a renovation loan sponsored by [FHA, Fannie Mae](https://www.nerdwallet.com/article/mortgages/203k-and-homestyle-mortgage-loans-for-home-renovation) or [Freddie Mac](https://www.nerdwallet.com/article/mortgages/choice-renovation-loan).

> The differences in these loans are in how they are lenient and how
> they are strict.
>
> - FHA 203(k) loans are more lenient about the borrower's credit and more strict about the renovation work that can be done.
> - Fannie Mae HomeStyle mortgages are more strict about the borrower's credit and more lenient about the renovation work that can be done.